# Function to Find longest word in wordlist created from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Again, having trouble wrapping my head around an assignment. I have a list which is created by user input, and I want to find the longest word from the list. I have been able to get the list but my output is incorrect and I am having an issue trying to compare the words from the list. I realize this is a duplicate question in a couple of other threads but after trying those suggestions I am still having an issue. This is what I have thus far, and thank you in advance:

```
def find_longest_word(wordList):  
    longest=''
    previous=''
    for word in wordList:
        if len(word)>len(longest):
            longest=word
            print(longest)
        else:
            previous=word
            print(previous)




print('Please enter a few words and I will find the longest word:','\n')         
words = input()
print('\n')
wordList = words.split()
print('The list of words entered is:','\n')
print(wordList)

find_longest_word(wordList)
```

Comment: You are never returning or printing the longest word. Instead, you print every single word, no matter if it is longer or shorter than the currently longest one.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`max(wordList, key=len)`

Comment: jsfan, correct.....I've been trying different things and this was my last attempt. at this stage I am spent and need a shove in the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
def find_longest_word(wordList):
    return max(wordList, key=len)
```

This simple line finds the maximum value of the wordList, comparing the values in the list by their length.

Comment: Why wrap a single function call in a function?

Comment: Because he wanted to make a function.

Comment: @jsfan also the line is complex enough to warrant a function, which would make calling it several times in the code much easier.

Comment: max() is a function. And, if this was called several times, you'd created the overhead of a redundant call every time.

Comment: I'm afraid this is very new to me, can you walk me through it. I placed it in the code but only get the word list.....no max

Comment: Your print statements are in the wrong place. Your algorithm works.

Comment: @ScrewzLewz The max function typically returns the maximum value of an array in Python. However, the function does not know how "max" is defined, that is to say, it does not how you want to determine that item a is greater than item b or vice versa. To solve this problem, we define "key=len," which says item a is greater than item b if its length is greater; the maximum item is that which has the longest length. Hope this is more helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Let's define a list of words as such:

```
wordList = ['word', 'longestWord', 'shorter']
```

You can find the index of the longest word with

```
maxIndex = max(enumerate(map(lambda x: len(x), wordList)), key=(lambda x: x[1]))
```

and finally see the longest word with:

```
wordList[maxIndex[0]]
```

Comment: Those are concepts I have not yet learned. While I can appreciate the simplicity in the code, I'm afraid I have to keep it more elementary for my purposes